# Correct Relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not too sure what tables I should have for this to work.

Basically, I currently have a table which stores information about a a-level physics paper. This paper has questions which need answers to.

To store this in the database I thought something like this would work (where bold represents a primary key and italics a foreign key):

Paper (**paper_id**, number_of_questions, paper_location, markscheme_location)

Question (***paper_id***, **question_number**)

However this wouldn't work as potentially the question could be '1)', '1)a)' or even '1)a)i)' This means I would have to have several tables each holding either the respected parts of the question number and have a relationship linking them all together? however the issue then arises that all questions would have to have all three parts? Thanks

Comment: Question (paper_id, questionId int,question_number varchar )? wll this work

Comment: u can have qno as 1 , 1 a  but qid will be different it will alsohelp when you have answer table

Comment: @YashveerSingh I thought that but wasnt sure if that would still cause problems when parsing it as seperating numbers from chars is easy but a and i are chars.. I could do something like this where its a var char formatted like '1-a-i' and split the '-' I guess? and would questionId be necessary or could a composite key of paper_id and question_number suffice - Thanks

Comment: but why it will be a problem we will treat each question as seprate not a parent question so question 1 has id 10 question 1 a has 11 and so on . i dont see any problem if you have sample data then it will be more clear and you can have key on paperid and questionid

Comment: 3 tables. Paper, question, sub_question. Sub questions could have relation to questions and contain level IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a parentId for questions. 
question table schema seems to be sth like this

Question (**question_id**, question_number, question_text, ***parent_id***, ***paper_id***)

parent_id is a foreign key related to question_id.

**Edit**:
Question rows:

```
(1, '2', 'foo', NULL, 4)
(2, 'a', 'bar', 1, 4)
(3, 'i', 'blah', 2, 4)
```

Results:

```
2. foo?
2.a. bar?
2.a.i blah?
```

Comment: So sort of like a parent-node relationship between questions - yes I think this will work, I will try to implement it now, Thank you :)

Comment: You would be storing nulls for the top level question (parent) which would cause issues relating all sub questions. Also, your sub questions are strings and not IDs, how would you assure correct order.

Comment: @newGuy you can traverse this tree recursively to assure correct order.

Comment: @x01saa would it be a DFS?

Comment: @cookies If you need optimal way, I think you must have a stack and a DFS algorithm.